# How to write to a new column if grep is true in r

Tags: r

This is probably simple but I would like to write to a new column if grep matches true in another column. Here is my code

```
ifelse(grepl("HALO|RFA|APC",Therap$ERPROCEDUREPERFORMED),Therap$RFA_EVENT=="RFA","nothing")
```

At the moment the column does not get written to. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
Therap$RFA <- ifelse(grepl("HALO|RFA|APC",Therap$ERPROCEDUREPERFORMED),"RFA","nothing")
```

---

In the `ifelse`, the usage is

```
ifelse(test, yes, no)
```

and the `test` is the logical condition.  But, in the OP's post, there are two logical conditions for 'test' and 'yes'.  I am guessing  the 'RFA' as the value.

---

**Edit:**
We can keep nesting other conditions, regarding [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010174):

```
Therap$RFA <- ifelse(grepl("HALO|RFA|APC", Therap$ERPROCEDUREPERFORMED), "RFA",
                     ifelse(grepl("XX|YY|ZZZZ", Therap$ERPROCEDUREPERFORMED), "XYZ",
                           "nothing"))
```

Comment: @SebastianZeki Thank you for the feedback.  I also posted a solution to your other post.  Please check it.

Comment: Yep. Haven't forgotten. needed to get this part sorted first before I test the other. Thanks

Comment: Some weird glitch. My fault. Sorry. Re-accepted now